# Can I save the changes of my some old commit, gotten via `git checkout`?

Tags: git

I am learning Git and I am reading [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/viewing-old-commits).

> You can use git checkout to view the “Make some import changes to
>   hello.py” commit as follows:
>
> `git checkout a1e8fb5`
>
> This makes your working directory match the exact state of the `a1e8fb5`
>   commit. You can look at files, compile the project, run tests, and
>   even edit files without worrying about losing the current state of the
>   project. Nothing you do in here will be saved in your repository. To
>   continue developing, you need to get back to the “current” state of
>   your project:
>
> `git checkout master`

But at this case I will lost my current changes in the working directory... What if my experiment was successfull and I want to save the result also? I.e. can I save the changes of my some old commit, gotten via `git checkout`?

Comment: Do you want to take your changes and apply them to `master`, or do you want to create a new branch based on `a1e8fb5`?

Comment: You can create a new branch from the commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout <commit-id> -b foo
```

### Explanation

**foo** : This can be the name of a backup branch you would want to place your checkout commmit.

**commit-id** : Well , this is the commit you would like to checkout.

### Result

Your checkout changes will be stored in a foo now that is local to you , so no worries. If you want to persist changes you made you'll have to use `git commit`; these commits will stay on `foo` from which you can reference them at any time.

Comment: A branch won't store uncommited changes, you probably didn't mean to imply this but the phrasing of your answer does. One has to commit - as usual - to persist changes.

Comment: The question says : to store changes done by some old commit.

Comment: *What if my __experiment__ was successfull and I want to save the result also?*, as I see it OP implies that he has made some changes (experiment) which he wants to save. I could be totally wrong though and the question is merely poorly phrased.

Comment: I agree with you, the question should be rephrased because the title and the description are contradicting.

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` will save your working copy changes to a separate space, and you can then take them out to your master branch with `git stash pop` (which might give you some conflicts, but such is life).

See [git-stash docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and [Stashing chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) in the Git book.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to save the result of your experiment, following the tutorial you link to. There, you can see that the commit log is shown as

> b7119f2 Continue doing crazy things
>  872fa7e Try something crazy
>   
>  a1e8fb5 Make some important changes to hello.py 
>  435b61d
>   Create hello.py 
>  9773e52 Initial import

In this case, none of your experiments are at risk of being lost -- they are saved in commits `872fa7e` and `b7119f2` and can easily be recovered using `git checkout` as you have learned.

che's answer is helpful if you have made some non-working or tentative changes that you are not quite ready to commit for whatever reason -- `git stash` is perfect in that situation. But in relation to the tutorial you are following, you have already committed your "crazy things" and can `checkout` these changes or previous states of the project at any time.